# Import values to xls from text file

Tags: vba, excel, xls

I have a text file containing some values and i need to populate these values to xls. How could i do that using macros. Suppose i have a text file as mentioned below:

Filename - data.txt

```
Records received in CIF file : 2682
Records loaded in CIF table : 2682
count : 2682
```

And i have xls format as

```
File name:  Output.csv                      
Load summary:                           
    "(A)
Records received in CIF file"   "(B)
Records loaded in CIF table (temp_location)"    "(C)
Records failed to load" 
    2682    2682    2682
```

I need to populate 2682 to  Output file as mentioned above but in xls. Here i want to use micro so that whenever i need to populate values to xls i want to do it by running macro and values will be automatically populated to xls.

Comment: @SysDragon I think the OP has tried getting us to write the code...

Comment: Please share what code you have so far. See [ask]

Answer (score 2):

so your code needs to do the following:

1. Open the data file, use **FileSystemObject**, see [MSDN Library: FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
2. Begin a loop reading through the lines of data in the test file (See [MSDN Library: How to use Looping Structures in VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141762)
3. Read the file for the end of *Records received in CIF file :* and take the value after that. See [MSDN Library: OpenAsTextStream Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265341%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and [MSDN Library: FSO ReadLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265367%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and for *String Manipulation*, see [Learn Excel: String Manipulation](http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/2012/04/vba-programming-string-manipulation/) and [Excel VBA: String Manipulation](http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-programming-string-manipulation.html) and of course: [MSDN Library: VB6/VBA String Functions Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443428%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
4. get the number from the string
5. Put that number in the result worksheet (See [How to Reference Cells and Ranges [Excel 2003 VBA Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221357%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [MS Excel Visual Basic Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa272254%28v=office.11%29.aspx))
6. next loop go back to step 2
7. Save worksheet using **Save** Method (See [MSDN Library: Excel Workbook Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197585.aspx)

that reading should get you started

Any problems or questions let us know **AFTER** you have tried writing some code

Philip